# Why are my triggers firing on scene load instead of when they are called?

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, collision-detection

I am using Unity 2021

I have a trigger function that rotates my player gameObject and switches a globally declared bool, which is stored in a script parked in an empty slot in the hierarchy, independent from all other elements. So far it only includes:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using Unity.VisualScripting;
 using Unity.VisualScripting.FullSerializer;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class Orientation : MonoBehaviour
 { public static bool Facing_Right = true; }
```

Facing_Right is changed to false when the player (in this instance an airplane set to move ceaselessly ahead) collides with the trigger. This trigger and its twin are boundaries to keep the player confined to the playing area.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
 public class RightBoundary : MonoBehaviour
 {
     private Vector3 current_rot;
 
     private void Start()
     {
         gameObject.tag = ("Player");
         current_rot = transform.eulerAngles;
     }
 
     void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Player)
     {
         print("Right Boundary Triggered"); 
         Player.transform.Rotate(0, current_rot.y - 180, 0);
         Orientation.Facing_Right = false;
     }
 }
```

Facing_Right is called upon in a separate controller script. It reverses the control orientation of my player from right to left respectively (duh). THAT script functions perfectly... EXCEPT, because the above script RightBoundary is triggered (three times) when the scene loads, Facing_Right instantly has its value set to false before any contact with my player the controls are reversed at the start of play; but The player's rotation only occurs upon colliding with the trigger. I have an identical copy of the above script (that also goes off three times just before RightBoundary does) as a boundary on the opposite end of the playing field, only it will set Facing_Right back to "true". It works as intended when the now reversed player flies into its trigger zone. No hiccups. Game play continues as planned after the first contact with RightBoundary. The player can ping-pong merrily back and forth with the switching controller layout all day if they want.

So, to restate, why does RightBoundary trigger immediately when the scene loads but only to set the value of Facing_Right to false, yet doesn't affect the players velocity?

Attempted fixes include: Using a public Target to identify my gameObject. Commenting out the command that switches Facing_Right's value. Removing the script Orientation from the hierarchy all together. Checking and double checking all of my tags. Combing my script for any possible reason to set off Facing_Right ahead of the trigger. Nothing. Console only prints that LeftBoundary (the other trigger) and RightBoundary have gone off three times each before settling down to regular behavior.

Comment: Unity 3.4.1? Now it's 2023, are you a time traveler?

Comment: You don't check if it is actually the player entering the trigger before you do your magic. Try printing `Player.gameObject.name` to identify what is actually causing the trigger event. Velocity isn't affected because you don't touch it in your script. You only change the rotation and set the bool.

Comment: Solved it. Simple and stupid mistake. My trigger was interaction with another gameObject. just saying that there was a gameObject.Tag("Player") wasn't enough I needed to use an if statement with CompareTag to turn my trigger's full attention to my intended collider.